# Godaddy email forwarders not working when sending from php mail

Tags: email, dns

I have an email forwarder set up on my GoDaddy account, which works fine when sending from an individual email account, but when I sent to it from a PHP script, it never gets received.

Here are a few additional details (I feel like the first two items here might be key in figuring out the answer):

- The email forwarder is on a GoDaddy account with a domain name. The Website for this domain name is hosted on another godaddy account. The nameservers set on the Domain name account are the default name servers (The website is working properly, because both accounts are GoDaddy).
- I have tried setting the email forwarder up on the hosting account instead of the domain name account. Interestingly, the email then does receive emails from php mail, but it does not receive emails sent directly from an email account. Instead, I get the error message "Your message wasn't delivered to *name@xxx.com* because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail."
- I can successfully send an email to any other email account from the same php script, so the problem is not my php mail function
- I had made some changes to MX records at one point, but then changed them back. A GoDaddy support tech said that they were correct and should work
- I've spent lots of time with Godaddy support, they said that they can not help me since the email forwarder is "working" when sent from a regular email account.

Comment: It's possible that email got rejected and never reached the inbox. Then it won't have anything to forward.

Comment: Got the answer through another forum. Here's the solution for anybody else that comes across this post. 

The hosting account website is on a cPanel server, with an add-on domain.

What you need to do is to go onto that server and under mail, there is a mail routing option - by default it is usually set to auto or local - you need to change it to remote - otherwise when the server (website) tries to send an email to an address at the domain it tries to deliver it to mailbox on the server itself